# How to call dbus methods in Awesome WM?

Tags: dbus, awesome-wm

I want to send dbus messages to other applications from Awesome WM. However, the documentation for Awesome's dbus interfact is pretty minimalistic, and I can't find any examples. How to do that? For example, I want to use the `Inhibit` function in `org.freedesktop.login1`.

Comment: Use D-Feet to get a nice list of available interfaces and its method, allowing you to also play with these methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awesome's built-in poor man's DBus wrapper barely contains enough support for DBus to have its built-in notification daemon (naughty) work: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/259c4f716fbd08b4507ebb4cb4d40fe5cbabed0f/dbus.c#L858-L870

This API allows you to implement an object available via DBus and to emit signals, but not to call DBus methods. Looking at [some docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/), it seems like the `Inhibit` interface is a method that you have to call. Even worse - it returns a file descriptor!

With lots of reading of GIO's documentation, I came up with the following (hopefully self-explanatory; but also please read https://github.com/pavouk/lgi/blob/master/docs/gio.md) example:

```
local lgi = require("lgi")
local Gio = lgi.require("Gio")
local GLib = lgi.require("GLib")

-- Workaround for https://github.com/pavouk/lgi/issues/142
local function bus_get_async(type)
    Gio.bus_get(type, nil, coroutine.running())
    local a, b = coroutine.yield()
    return Gio.bus_get_finish(b)
end

local function inhibit(bus, what, who, why, mode)
    local name = "org.freedesktop.login1"
    local object = "/org/freedesktop/login1"
    local interface = "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager"
    local message = Gio.DBusMessage.new_method_call(name, object, interface, "Inhibit")
    message:set_body(GLib.Variant("(ssss)",
        { what, who, why, mode }))

    local timeout = -1 -- Just use the default
    local result, err = bus:async_send_message_with_reply(message, Gio.DBusSendMessageFlags.NONE,
        timeout, nil)

    if err then
        print("error: " .. tostring(err))
        return
    end

    if result:get_message_type() == "ERROR" then
        local _, err = result:to_gerror()
        print("error: " .. tostring(err))
        return
    end

    local fd_list = result:get_unix_fd_list()
    local fd, err = fd_list:get(0)
    if err then
        print("error: " .. tostring(err))
        return
    end

    -- Now... somehow turn this fd into something we can close
    return Gio.UnixInputStream.new(fd, true)
end

Gio.Async.call(function()
    local bus = bus_get_async(Gio.BusType.SYSTEM)
    local a = inhibit(bus, "shutdown:sleep", "hi, it's me!", "Just because", "delay")
    print("got lock")
    io.popen("sleep 10"):read("*a")
    a:async_close()
    -- Speed up deletion of the GDBusMessage that still references the FD
    collectgarbage("collect")
    collectgarbage("collect")

    print("released lock")
    io.popen("sleep 10"):read("*a")
end)()
```

If you want, you can turn the above into something synchronous by replacing calls to `async_foo` with calls to `foo_sync`. That also allows to get rid of the hack to make `bus_get_async()` work and the `Gio.Async.call` wrapper around everything.